# Retrieve value from object member through std::bind

Tags: c++, bind

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a bind expression not return an object, but an member *of* the object. Here is the idea (I want to get `val` directly from `B`):

```
struct A
{
    A(float _val) : val(_val) {}
    float val;
};

struct B
{
    B(float _val) : a(_val) {}
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    B b{ 2.0f };
    auto get_a_from_b = std::bind(&B::a, std::placeholders::_1);
    const A& a = get_a_from_b(b); // ok

    auto get_val_from_a = std::bind(&A::val, std::placeholders::_1);
    float val = get_val_from_a(a); // ok, val = 2.0f

    // error
    auto get_val_from_b = std::bind(&B::a::val, std::placeholders::_1);
    auto x = get_val_from_b(b);
}
```

In particular, can the concept of `B::a::val` work or is it conceptually wrong? (I am aware that this can be achieved with a lambda, but that's not the question.)

Thanks!

Comment: `&B::a` is a member pointer. You're conceptually wrong. To solve your question, just use lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as liliscent said, it can't be done directly. You may, however, link it together like so:

```
int val = std::mem_fn(&A::val)(std::mem_fn(&B::a)(b));
```

(`mem_fn` is the better function for this endeavour).

This can be made more compact with its own function:

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int _val = 0) : val(_val) {}
    int val;
};
struct B
{
    B(int _val = 0) : a(_val) {}
    A a;
};

template<typename Elem, typename Head, typename... Tail>
constexpr decltype(auto) getElement(const Elem& _elem, Head&& _head, Tail&&... _tail)
{
    auto fn = std::mem_fn(std::forward<Head>(_head));
    if constexpr(sizeof...(_tail) == 0)
    {
        return fn(_elem);
    }
    else
    {
        return getElement(fn(_elem), std::forward<Tail>(_tail)...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    B b{ 7 };
    int i = getElement(b, &B::a, &A::i); // get the a from B first, then get the val from that a
    int j = getElement(b.a, &A::i);

    return 0;
}
```

But the more you stack if up, the more the brevity advantage compared to the lambda vanishes. Oh well.